# How to point to a pointer of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a program that can modify rows and cols from a function of a function. I don't understand how to do pointer of a pointer.

```
void changeNum(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
  changeNum2(*setRows,*setCol);
}
void changeNum2(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
  *setRows=5;
  *setCol=5;
}
int main() {
  int*row=10;
  int* col=10;
  changeNum(&row,&col);
  printf("%d %d",row,col);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any textbook/online course/tutor should be able to help you out.

Comment: The question title alone indicates that your are approaching becoming a three-star-programmer (http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Please reconsider.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
  int*row=10;
  int* col=10;
```

This is wrong. Assigning hardcoded address. You don't want this

```
  int row=10;
  int col=10;
```

How to get the address of the row and col?

`&row` and `&col`.

How to pass it to function?

Call it, `changeNum(&row,&col);`

```
void changeNum(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
     ...       
}
```

How to pass pointer to pointer?

```
void changeNum(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
    chnageNum2(&setRows, &setCol);
}
```

`ChangeNum2` how it would change value?

```
void chnageNum2(int **setRows, int **setCol){
    **setRows = 110;
    **setCol = 110;
}
```

---

Can we do the same change using `changeNum()` only?

Yes we can do that.

```
void changeNum(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
     *setRows = 110;
     *setCol = 110;        
}
```

Definitely check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Grab a book. It will help a lot.

The complete code will be

```
void changeNum(int*setRows, int *setCol)
{
  changeNum2(&setRows,&setCol);
}
void changeNum2(int**setRows, int **setCol)
{
  **setRows=5;
  **setCol=5;
}
int main(void) {
  int row=10;
  int col=10;
  changeNum(&row,&col);
  printf("%d %d",row,col);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void changeNum(int*, int*);
void changeNum2(int*, int*);

void changeNum(int* setRows, int *setCol) {
    changeNum2(setRows,setCol);
}

void changeNum2(int* setRows, int *setCol) {
    *setRows=5;
    *setCol=5;
}

int main() {
    int row=10;
    int col=10;
    changeNum(&row, &col);
    printf("%d %d\n", row, col);
    return 0;
}
```

It takes sometime to grasp that every C function parameter is passed by value. So you can safely pass `setRows` pointer to the second function simply by its value.

Also, it's necessary to declare previously the function `changeNum2`, I've included the declaration without parameter names to clarify it's possible.

I strongly recommend reading this book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language, specially chapter 5 (Pointers and arrays).

You can find a PDF copy easily. It's where I finally learned this concept.